# Any easy way to override method for existing object at runtime

Tags: java, object, runtime, overriding

Let's say I have a domain object, Here is the pseudocode

```
public class SampleClass {
  id
  title
  ... a lot of other fields from database
  public boolean equals(AnotherObj) {
       return this.id.equals(AnotherObj.id);
  }
}
```

The equals method is based on the id, which works for most scenarios. But in one scenario, the two objects shall be considered equal if the titles are the same. **The objects are put in list and list.contains(obj) and list.indexOf(obj) is heavily invoked for business logic, which depends on the equals method.**

How to override the equals method at runtime? The sampleClass object could contain complicated tree childrens and I don't want to copy it in the memory.

I want to create a wrapper for the existing object. The wrapper only contains the specific equals method, all other method call should still be passed to the existing object.

I looked into cglib but it has to generate the target object by itself, it cannot wrap an existing object.

Any easy way?

Comment: Danger: this is NOT `Object`'s `.equals()` you are overriding here

Comment: You want to implement a [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) and pass through calls to the proxied object in most scenarios but do something different based on the underlying class of the proxied object?

Comment: I know this is not object's equal. That is why I only want to put that specific equal in the wrapper.

Comment: When you're convoluting yourself to this degree, it tells you you're looking in the wrong place for the solution.

Comment: Then see my answer; requires Guava, but Guava is a gold mine

Comment: @fge and this is what (at)override is for...

Comment: I'd avoid implementing it this way if possible.  For typical DB 'value object' classes (which generally include some sort of ID file, as in your case) it is often not intuitively clear whether `equals()` means same instance, same ID, or same everything (all fields).  Your code will likely be clearer if you use `Object.equals(a.getId(), b.getId())` (or an equivalent null-safe utility method) instead of `Object.equals(a, b)`.  (BTW `Object.equals()` was add for 1.8 and has long been needed!)

Comment: @Paul you mean `Objects.equals()`, right? And it is since 1.7

Comment: Yes, I do.  Thanks fge.  In my own code base there has been a `Utils.equals(a, b)` for years.  (Guess I should get use to using the 'real' one.)  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are actually talking about `Object`'s `.equals()`/`.hashCode()`, which is not what your code currently does, you can do that using Guava's [`Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0.1/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html).

Create an equivalence:

```
public final class SampleClassIdEquivalence
    extends Equivalence<SampleClass>
{
    // override .doEquivalent(), .doHash()
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
final Equivalence<SampleClass> byId = new SampleClassIdEquivalence();

byId.equivalent(o1, o2);

Set<Equivalence.Wrapper<SampleClass>> set = ...

set.add(byId.wrap(whatever));
```

Then you can create other equivalences for equality by name or whatever; your choice.

In fact, `Equivalence` is pretty much to `.equals()`/`.hashCode()` what `Comparator` is to `Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks, this is one solution. I think I need override wrap method to allow me get back the original class being wrapped. Weird, guava API does not provide that.

Comment: oh, after look into the api of Wrapper class, I found the get() method can return the original object being wrapped. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to wrap these objects, I would modify the class so that it understands what it should be checking (in each scenario) in its `equals` method. Then in this particular situation, just set whatever state member (or whatever it is) that tells the object how `equals` should work. Just be sure not to break the contract.

I would also recommend actually overriding `Object#equals` (e.g., make sure your `equals` accepts `Object`, not just `AnotherObj`). (And of course, as always, do `hashCode` as well.)

But if you *do* want to do this, and you want to do it with `equals`, it sounds like a job for [the Facade pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) It's a bit of a pain in Java: You have to create another whole class that accepts the object as an argument in the constructor, implements all methods except `equals` by just calling them on the object, and then (of course) implements `equals` differently.

So basically:

```
class SampleSubclass extends SampleClass {
    SampleClass inst;

    SampleSubclass(SampleClass inst) {
        this.inst = inst;
    }

    @override
    String someMethod() {
        return inst.someMethod();
    }

    // ...and so on...

    @override
    public boolean equals(AnotherObj other) { // <== But this really should accept Object, not AnotherObj
        // ... implementation...
    }
}
```

Comment: I considered this solution too. I need setState before I need that specific equal logic and once that is done, I need clear the state. If I forget clear the state, it will be a bug not easy to detect.

Comment: @YaoDong: Then to me, frankly, this doesn't sound like a job for `equals` at all, not if it's a transient thing.

Comment: @YaoDong: But this does sound like a job for the Facade pattern (I just wouldn't use it with `equals`). I've updated to give more on that.